# Can we use dash to connect two independent clause?

Tags: punctuation

> The most famous among these are the still-relevant Olympic **games. These** games tested the strength of warriors from different provinces who gathered in front of cheering crowds to represent their hometowns.

Can I use a dash here to connect them? If the second clause explains the first clause and both of them are independent, can we use then? Please me the rule of the dash?

Answer (score 2):

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114/should-i-use-a-semicolon-or-a-dash-to-connect-two-closely-related-sentences here's a good source. This provides you information regarding the use of dashes. The second sentence seems "reinforcing" enough that you could get away with a dash here. But like I said, that answer I linked provides excellent examples.

Comment: That answer at ELU isn't bad but I don't agree there are "standard" guidelines.  The difference between the dash and the semicolon is *tone*, not *syntax*.  In any of the examples you could swap the semicolon for the dash without changing anything else the sentence, e.g. *When dinosaurs agree on something, they'll often high-five one another -- dinosaurs are all about high-fives.*  The semicolon is stately, calm, and almost professorial, while the dash is loud, brash, and stentorian.  You use the semicolon to lecture, and the dash to orate.